CSS selector for everything except for images
How would I use CSS to style all elements that are not images? I tried using
body:not(img) {
    filter: grayscale(1);
}

but this does not work.

@connexo because :not(img) matches the html element, the body element, and any other elements wrapping an image, the images will end up rendered in greyscale, which is not what @antoine wants.

A greyscale filter on any element will apply to all its contents. So your selector not only needs to exclude images, it also needs to exclude elements which have an image descendant. This is the selector you need:
:not(img, :has(img))

Here is a snippet to demonstrate this working. Images, whether they are children of the body or deeper in the document hierarchy, remain in colour, while the rest of the document becomes greyscale. Tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on Mac.


.p1 {
  color: red;
}

.p2 {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(110,229,255,1) 0%, rgba(192,118,255,1) 100%);
}

:not(img, :has(img)) {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
<p>This is black</p>
<p class="p1">This is red</p>
<p class="p2">This has a blue gradient background</p>
<a href="https://this-page-intentionally-left-blank.org">
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/840/120">
</a>
<img src="http://picsum.photos/id/845/120">
<div>
  <a href="https://this-page-intentionally-left-blank.org">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/840/120">
  </a>
  <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/845/120">
</div>




Thank you for the snippet and explanation!

I realized that this makes clickable images that have links unclickable. Is there a way to circumvent this? For some odd reason, turning everything to grayscale still makes these images clickable, but when using your filter it doesn't.

I have updated my snippet to include links on two of the images. As you can see, these links still work with the filter applied. The problem you are seeing probably has a more complex cause. (It would not surprise me if using :has within :not has undesirable side-effects – browser support for :has is relatively new.) I suggest you try to create a minimal example which reproduces the problem you are seeing, and post it as another question. Then come back here and add a comment with a link to the new question.

Hmm, I was experiencing this issue with certain Wikipedia images. I'll ask another question and tag you if I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Doing :not on the body will target elements directly on the body.
What you're after is something like
body *:not(img) {}

This targets all elements '*' where the element is not the img tag.
Although you may need to tweak this, as doing this might also interfere with your images depending on things overlapping (such as parent divs of the images).

I would say that body is redundant here

I guess so, it depends on if you want it to be literally everything. I guess other filtering can be done by class name depending on the severity of the filter.

@AnnaK *:not(img) will selector the body and html element which I think it's not intended so we need to keep the body in the selector.

I tried this on a Wikipedia page, and it doesn't work. For some context, I am trying to make everything but images grayscale on a webpage by injecting custom CSS. Using that selector made everything including the images grayscale. I verified with inspect element that the image has an  tag in the html. Is there something else that's needed?

@antoine you are correct, this solution does not work. See my answer.
